# how to minimize js and css files using gradle.build file

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build.gradle

i have a phonegap application. I use gradle to sign and zipalign app building it but i want to use gradle to minimize javascript and css files before building a release apk.

Is there any way to do this? could you help cant find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two plugins out there that will help you with this task:

- [Gradle JS plugin](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin)
- [Gradle CSS plugin](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-css-plugin)

Please check the plugin documentation for more information on how to integrate it into your build.